# Format a date with dynamic quantity of milliseconds digits with sed

Tags: regex, date, sed, hive

I retrieve dates from a database and format them, using sed, in order to compare with other dates from another database.

The two databases are not the same (MSSQL and Hive).

The date from MSSQL is correctly formatted with the following:

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)\ \([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\)\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/g")
```

However, I do not know how to do it with the date from Hive.

The target output is: YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

The input from Hive is `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S` OR `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS` OR `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

This is caused by Hive ignoring somewhere during insertion the 0 digits in the milliseconds.

For example:

`YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.XX0` will become `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.XX` in Hive

`YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.X00` will become `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.X` in Hive

`YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000` will become `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0` in Hive

**Is there a sed command that can handle all of these cases, or another solution should be used ?**

Comment: Replace `\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)` with `\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/pf8N8N)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace `\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)` with `\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)`:

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)\ \([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\):\([0-9]\{2\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/g"
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/pf8N8N).

The point is that your original regex matched three digits at the end (so, it required three milliseconds to be present at the end). With `\{1,3\}`, you require one, two or three digits to be present there.